# How to reduce image size in multi-part FormData file upload

Tags: angularjs, angular, angular-dart

html

```
 <form #form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file"  #upload name='uploadingFiles' (change)="uploadFiles(form)"  multiple>
</form>
```

Angular

```
 void uploadFiles(form) {
    var formData = new FormData(form);
    final request = new HttpRequest();
    request.open('POST', 'http://localhost:8080/uploadMulti');
    request.upload.onProgress.listen((ProgressEvent e) {
      print('progress');
    });
    request.onLoad.listen((e) {
      print('Uploaded');
    });
    request.send(formData);
  }
```

How can I put  image  manipulation  code  here  to  reduce  an image  that is  4000X4000   to  600X600   and  then  replace  it  in the formData  before sending ?  Is it possible or is the  formData  just  meta-data  passed to  the  server  and  then  server  uses  that  to pull image  bytes one  file at  a time ?

Answer (score 0):

Angular has a good package to make a compression on the image before you upload it to your server.

you can use this https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-image-compress

and here is a good article if you have doubts about who you can do it.

https://medium.com/swlh/compress-image-and-send-it-to-an-api-in-angular-bc48e6ed3835